# Flutter | How to show a Hint Text when a value is entered

Tags: flutter, text, textfield, hint, suffix

**I want the Hint Text to remain even when Text is entered in the TextField:**
[image: I want to do the same]

But if I give TextField something like "hintText:" in simple way, Hint Text disappears when TextField is entered: [image: Current status.]

**What should I do so that the hintText doesn't disappear even when a value is entered in the TextField?**

.
.
.
I tried the following:

I. I tried using the suffix widget. But it appears from the end of the TextField. (If it was possible to make the suffix widget appear after the text, I think the problem would have been solved.) : [image: Ignore the malfunction]

II. Obviously Prefix Widget can't help here : [image: with Prefix Widget]

*Any answers are welcome, thanks.*

Comment: you need to make a custom text field ... some thing like this https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_fields

Comment: Hey have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use label to be visible at the top of the TextField & the hint u can simply add below line:

```
floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always
```

full example is given below

```
TextFormField(
  controller: textController,
  style: theme.textTheme.bodyText2,
  keyboardType: keyboardType ?? TextInputType.number,
  enableInteractiveSelection: false,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: labelText,
      labelStyle: theme.textTheme.headline6,
      suffixText: suffixText ?? '',
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide:
            BorderSide(color: theme.textTheme.bodyText2.color, width: 2),
      ),
      hintText: '0.0',
      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always),
  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter some text';
    }
    return null;
  },
  onChanged: (String text) => onChange(text),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you seem to have misunderstood the question:

The HintText should not disappear even after entering a value in the TextField. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvwAK.gif